# How to write simple, extensible, modular Javascript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, extensibility, modular-design

I need a mechanism whereby people can extend my base code with their own modules - but I'm struggling to come-up with a simple mechanism to do that.

Example: a function called 'test' which users can extend.  Each user module is loaded after the original - so each one needs to build on the last (the order they're loaded should not matter or can be controlled by naming)

I started to play with something like this

```
var test = function() { // the master function
    console.log("1");
}

var ltest = test; // module 1
var test = function() {
    ltest();
    console.log("2");
}

var ltest2 = test; // module 2
var test = function() {
    ltest2();
    console.log("3");
}
```

Then, when 'test' is called, it will run everyone's code (assuming no-one forgot their callback!!)

That works, but it relies on each module declaring it's own, unique 'callback' variable (ltest, ltest2) - if someone uses the same variable, we'll get a 'call stack exceeded' as those variables are global in scope...

Can anyone suggest a cleverer/better system - or point me to some examples of the same thing?

There's loads of material on inheritance but I don't want to create new things which extend the old one - I just want to extend the old one!!

p.s. taking the anonymous function stuff from the module pattern - I got this

```
var test = function() {
    console.log("1");
}

(function() {
    var oldtest = test;
    test = function() {
        oldtest();
        console.log("2");
    }
}())

(function() {
    var oldtest = test;
    test = function() {
        oldtest();
        console.log("3");
    }
}())
```

Which is probably the simplest solution to my question - but not necessarily the best system to use (as it's dependant on the author to remember to callback the code - a dodgy module would break everything)

Comment: You might get some ideas from [Addy Osmani's Design Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/).

Comment: Did you take a look at TypeScript? http://www.typescriptlang.org

Answer (score 1):

The [Module Pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) is what you need.

In particular the 'Augmentation' or 'Loose Augmentation' patterns :

```
var MODULE = (function (my) {
    var old_moduleMethod = my.moduleMethod;

    my.moduleMethod = function () {
        // method override, has access to old through old_moduleMethod...
    };

    return my;
}(MODULE || {}));
```

Comment: This is also very interesting - if nothing else my understanding of variable scope and anonymous functions has exploded in the last 20 mins!!

Comment: I took the way that pattern uses anonymous functions to encapsulate values and I've updated the first question with it (as code doesn't show well in comments)

Answer (score 1):

You could make a function like this

```
function extendFunction(fn, pre, post) {
    return function () {
        var arg = arguments;
        if (pre) arg = pre.apply(this, arg);   // call pre with arguments
        arg = fn.apply(this, arg);             // call fn with return of pre
        if (post) arg = post.apply(this, arg); // call post with return of fn
        return arg;
    };
}
```

then extend as follows

```
var test = function () { // the master function
    console.log("1");
};
test = extendFunction(
    test, // function to extend
    null, // thing to do first
    function() {console.log("2");} // thing to do after
);
test = extendFunction(
    test,
    null,
    function() {console.log("3");}
);
test(); // 1, 2, 3
```

This is very different to the normal meaning of "extend" though, where you give new properties to *Objects* or set up *prototype* chains, and to "module" which normally involves wrapping all your code in a *function expression* so that you don't pollute the namespace.

Comment: This is very interesting - all these functions are part of a chain/waterfall of async events (related to storing or retrieving stuff from a NOSQL database) - so this approach would work really well I think...